# Full-text search limit not working in Go Couchbase

Tags: go, full-text-search, couchbase

I would like to implement a limit and offset based full-text search for my couchabse, but I have the following problem where I determine the limit for 10, and I getting back 13 results instead of (or different amounts of document keys).

So I have the following code:

```
q := query{
    Query: searchString,
    From:  offset,
    Limit: limit,
}

query := gocb.NewSearchQuery(indexName, q).Limit(limit).Skip(offset)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", query)
result, err := bucket.ExecuteSearchQuery(query)
if err != nil {
    return 0, resp, err
}
```

And the query looks like (because I print it out):

```
&{name:indexName data:{Query:{Query:+owner_id:randomID From:10 Limit:10} Size:10 From:10 Explain:false Highlight:<nil> Fields:[] Sort:[] Facets:map[] Ctl:<nil>}}
```

Here the `+owner_id:randomID` is the searchString and I add the From and Limit on both places.

I got the test failing because of:

```
couchbase_test.go:234: Length should be 10, instead of count: 13
```

This is the length of the `result.Hits()`.

So what am I doing wrong here? Sometimes it's running properly, but sometimes it's failing.

**UPDATE 1**

If I add the searchString directly into the NewSearchQuery like `gocb.NewSearchQuery(indexName, searchString)...` it won't find anything, because it should have the following format.

Comment: As far as I know, hits() will always return the total count of matches (Solr has the same behavior). If you want to ensure how many results you received, I suppose you have to iterate through what you received.

Comment: Hopefully the limit and offset should do this, on other way the pagination won't work properly.